# Bit shifting difference in Java and C++ - how to reconcile

Tags: java, c++, bit-manipulation

I have some code in C++ that I'm trying to port over to Java and there is a problem I can't solve.

It's easily seen with an example. At some stage in the C++ code, I have an unsigned int h with a value of 594076817. I then compute (h << 10). I get the result 2744271872.

In Java, I have a long 594076817. I then compute (h << 10) and I get 608334660608.

I understand/suspect that this is due to the differences in representation (unsigned vs signed) and have tried reading along those lines with no avail. What is the best way to get the Java code to get the same result as the C++ code?

Comment: This sounds like a 32-bit vs. 64-bit problem. Note that the value you're getting from Java is mathematically correct.

Comment: Bitwise AND with 0xFFFFFFFFL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ code appears to be operating on 32-bit ints.  Using Java's 32-bit integer type `int`, the code

```
int h = 594076817;
System.out.println(h << 10);
```

prints `-1550695424` (Java's `int`s are signed).  This is `2744271872` - 2<sup>32</sup>.  When the datatype is changed to the 64-bit integer type `long`, the answer changes:

```
long h = 594076817L;
System.out.println(h << 10);
```

This prints `608334660608`.  When you truncate everything beyond the lower 32 bits of `608334660608`, you get the `int` answer: `2744271872`.

To get the desired result, which seems to rely on overflow in C++, use `long` in Java, but bit-mask out the last 32 bits by bit-anding with `0xFFFFFFFFL`.

Comment: In C/C++ unsigned integer arithmetic does not overflow. Rather, it is computed mod 2^bits, where bits is the size of the unsigned integer datatype. Signed arithmetic can overflow, with undefined results (possibly a trap if the hardware supports that).